# Visual Studio 2015 indenting a multiline for statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, auto-indent

I'm trying to configure VS2015 to autoindent a for loop like this:

```
for( int index = 0;
     index < collection.size();
     ++index)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

I've tried a lot of combinations of autoindenting options but cant get what I want, I always get something like this:

```
for( int index = 0;
index < collection.size();
     ++index)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

which (to me) does not make any sense. Does anyone knows how to do this?

**Update**:

Updating to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 solved the issue. Should I close the question or answer it?

Comment: Take a look at [this and the associated  links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543426/automatically-insert-comments-in-c-code/14543594#14543594).

Comment: Is it working if you press [CTRL] [K] [D] ? (when pressing on D, CTRL is still pressed)

Comment: Ctrl-K + Ctrl-D gives me the same results, the for is "wrongly" indented.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to produce the same result that you got, but mine defaulted to the one you are trying to get. I changed some of the settings in the C# text editor and possibly figured out what the problem is.

If you go to tools > options, select the 'text editor' drop down arrow then 'C#' drop down arrow, go to 'Tabs' and change 'Indenting' to smart.

Mine was set to 'Smart' by default, but when I produced the same result as you, I set to 'Block'.

I guess you really could just go to All Languages if you are working with other ones beside C# and want the same configuration. There are the same indenting options

Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: I'm using C++ here, and I just tried all three settings and none of them gave me the results I want.